# Existe alguma palavra em português que reflita a palavra inglesa "pedantic"?

Tags: vocabulário, tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

No inglês técnico, é relativamente comum recorrer ao adjetivo *[pedantic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pedantic?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic)* para descrever uma pessoa ou entidade excessivamente preocupada com detalhes minuciosos, normalmente de forma neutra (nem positiva nem negativa). Tal definição é usada em *flags* nos compiladores da GNU ([GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)).

> [***Pedantic:***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pedantic) adjective
>
> 1. ostentatious in one's learning.
> 2. **overly concerned with minute details or formalisms, especially in teaching**.

Lamentavelmente, a tradução literal da mesma palavra no português, *pedante*, não tem o mesmo significado:

> [***Pedante:***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pedante) adjectivo de dois géneros e substantivo de dois géneros
>
> 1. Que ou quem se dá ares de sábio, de pessoa circunspecta.
> 2. Charlatão.
> 3. Que ou quem mostra modos de dizer ou de fazer, que não só não é natural, mas até forçado; que ou quem é afectado. = PRETENSIOSO

Não querendo recorrer a uma expressão de muitas palavras, nem a termos que são ambíguos ou não correspondem na totalidade à definição (*minucioso*, *perfecionista*, *exagerado*, ... ), que palavra portuguesa será a mais indicada para este significado sem se tornar demasiado informal? Se não é possível, quais seriam as palavras mais indicadas?

Comment: A tradução, "pedante", é pejorativa. A melhor opção me parece ser utilizar "minucioso" ou "perfeccionista" que são considerados neutros, adicionando detalhes sobre o contexto do Perfeccionismo ou da Minuciosidade se e quando necessário.

Comment: E_net4: Para mim, «*excessivamente* preocupado» é pejorativo. Na linguagem corrente, *pedantic* é pejorativo. Se o significado em computação é neutro, então desvia-se do da linguagem corrente, e seria preciso tirar o *excessivamente* (talvez, dentro do razoável, haja pessoa mais e menos minuciosas, e se chame *pedantic* às que são, dentro do razoável, mais minuciosas?)

Comment: pedante é pejorativo da mesma maneira que pedantic.

Comment: Concordo com @Lambie; nunca entendi que _pedantic_ fosse neutro, em que pese o seu uso como chave de configuração do **gcc**. Sempre entendi como sendo um termo depreciativo, e usado também na informática neste sentido.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creio que como você já elencou algumas boas opções, não é bem uma questão de obter uma resposta, mas mais de receber opiniões sobre qual a melhor escolha.

De qualquer forma, entendo que "minucioso" enquadra-se bem como uma tradução, uma vez que mesmo em português há certa correlação entre pedante e minucioso.

Ainda, a definição de dicionário tanto para "pedante" como para "pedantic", irá variar de acordo com a fonte e, em alguns casos, coincide (*). Assim, também não acho que a tradução "pedante" é tão ruim assim, mas para a definição que você procura (como no caso dos compiladores), "minucioso" parece melhor.

(*) Exemplo http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedantic , http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/pedantic e http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=pedante

Comment: Eu ia responder, mas vi que você mencionou "minucioso". Concordo que essa é a melhor tradução. Também concordo que "pedante" é mais pejorativo em português do que em inglês. Muito embora, as vezes a palavra "pedantic" também é usada de forma pejorativa em inglês (não é o caso do exemplo dos compiladores), e ai "pedante" funciona perfeitamente. :)

Answer (score 5):

Além dos já citados "meticuloso" e "perfeccionista", sugiro `"metódico"`, `"sistemático"`, `"formalista"` e `"preciosista"` como possíveis traduções, dependendo do contexto.

Acredito que não exista uma tradução que tenha exatamente o mesmo conceito e uso, mas uma definição de "formalista" parece próxima do que você quer.

http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/formalista

Veja que o Wikcionário traz **"formalista"** como `"amigo do formalismo"`, e **"formalismo"** como `"apego a normas de comportamento; rigidez"`.

https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/formalista

No entanto, parece-me que "formalista" abarca bem a parte `_formalism_` mas não a parte `_minute details_`. Eu diria que o `_pedantic_` seria **`"minucioso e formalista"`**.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo o site [Wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/enpt/pedant)
  o termo pode ser traduzido como pedante ou meticuloso

Em definições do próprio inglês: purist (purista)

Acho que purista pode ser uma boa tradução que atende à duvida.